# Trying to return two outputs from fortran to matlab with mex

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex

So this is the code in question. I simply take a number and multiply it by 2. I'm pretty much appending it twice to the output array. in matlab I do a=timestwo(2) I get 4, but when I do [a,b]=timestwo(2) I would expect to get a=4, b=4, but instead matlab just crashes. I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but some insight would be great.

```
   C     Create matrix for the return argument.
          plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, 0)
          plhs(2)=mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, 0)
          y_ptr = mxGetPr(plhs(1))
          y_ptrr=mxGetPr(plhs(2))

    C     Call the computational subroutine.
            call timestwo(y_output, x_input)
            call timestwo(y_outputt,x_inputt)
    C     Load the data into y_ptr, which is the output to MATLAB.
          call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(y_output,y_ptr,size)
          call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(y_outputt,y_ptrr,size)
```

Comment: This code is not entirely reproducible in results.  What is `y_output` and `y_outputt` equal to?  Same for `x_input` and `x_inputt`.  Are you sure you made `y_output` and `y_outputt` point to `plhs(1)` and `plhs(2)` respectively? Same goes for `x_inputt` and `prhs`.

Comment: @rayryeng Not sure why, (no idea of fortram) but tht piece of code seems allrigth for the outputs....

Comment: To clarify x_input=x_inputt, y_input=y_inputt=2*x_input. I guess what I have seems logical to me. When i do a=timestwo(2) i get the correct number back, but from my code above i appended two outputs. Which I would think would be put in a,b if i call like this [a.b]=timestwo(2)